# We have used android Studio and face this error

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: okhttp3/Address.class**

We have used this dependencies

[image]

Comment: PLease be more specific with your title so that it can be more easily identified

Comment: Hi we have facing this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: okhttp3/Address.class

Answer (score 0):

check that the versions are correct and if you are enabling offline mode disable it from file -> settings -> Build,execution,Deployment -> gradle ->unCheck offline mode -> ok
 then build the app again and if it doesn't work press on sync project with gradle files

Comment: what is your compile sdk version?

Comment: my compileSdkVersion is '25'

Comment: then change your dependencies with red line by changing their version to 25.3.1